# After creating an Azure Web App using ARM Template, can we pass the web app name as parameter to YAML pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am new to devops and struck at this. I am working on developing Infrastructure as code for the project, which has multiple APIs, an Angular,a database project and some other components.

I have created - 
  ARM Templates to deploy the resources to Azure
  YAML file to build and deploy the code to the App.

What I couldn't figure out is how to group these tasks. I need to trigger the yaml Pipeline after ARM Template deployment is done and pass the WebApp name to the pipeline so that the Artifacts can be deployed.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hi, how the things going now? Does the below script can successfully achieve what you want? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you are still facing some issues please leave a comment so we can still help you :-)

Comment: Thanks Merlin. I have solved this with the similar approach. Your script is almost identical to mine. I have up voted the answer. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As normal, we doesn't execute ARM template deploy task and Azure app service deploy task separately. Execute ARM deploy in the first stage, then in stage 2, get the `WebsiteName` or `ResourceGroupName` which from previous stage output:

[image]

For YAML, you should configure it like this(this just a part definition to show the key code about `ARM` and `APP` deploy with YAML):

```
variables:
  WebAppName: {the webapp name you want to used}
stages:
  - stage: ARMdeploy
    jobs:
      - job: ARM
        steps:
        - checkout: none
        - task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: '{Subscription name}'
            action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
            resourceGroupName: '{resource group name }'
            location: 'Central US'
            templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
            csmFile: '{json file}'
            overrideParameters: '-webAppName $(WebAppName)'
            deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
  - stage: APPdeploy
    dependsOn: ARMdeploy
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - job: APP
        steps:
        - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
          displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: MerlinAngular-webapp'
          inputs:
            ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
            azureSubscription: '{Subscription name}'
            appType: 'webApp'
            WebAppName: '$(WebAppName)'
            packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

In my ARM json file, I define the parameter name `webAppName`, and use the value which from task instead of using `parameter.json` file

[image]

And in the YAML configuration, use `overrideParameters: '-WebAppName $(WebAppName)'` to override this parameter value. Since `WebAppName` is a pre-defined variable which can be get value in all stages of one release pipeline. Also, I set the `APP deploy stage` as depending on `ARM deploy stage`'s succeed. Now, after the ARM deployment is done, the WebApp name will be pass to the job so that the APP deploy can be deployed with this WebApp name.

---

But, since you did not show how's your ARM template structure, if you defined the WebApp name in the `parameter.json` file, you need to install the extension [ARM Outputs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=keesschollaart.arm-outputs&targetId=3ec66d6c-317d-423e-a056-b014031f2871&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList) then use the task `ARM Outputs` to get this `WebApp name` variable after the ARM template deploy finished.

This task can convert all output of ARM deploy into variable, now you can still use `$(xxx)` to pass the value into APP deploy task.

Hope these method can help you.